# How to add relationships in JAX-RS via RESTful web service?

Tags: rest, jax-rs, restful-url, restful-architecture

OK I can GET POST PUT DELETE simple resources (entities) in my RESTful web service

ex.

```
/rest/foos
/rest/foos/1 

/rest/bars
/rest/bars/1
```

But how to handle adding relationships ex. @OneToMany, @ManyToMany between this relationships using RESTful web service. 
Suppose I have several Foo entities and several Bar entities how to establish relationships Bar 1 has Foo 3 , etc.

I have such approach to GET this relationships:

```
GET /rest/bars/1/foos
```

Above returns collection of foos related with Bar(id=1)

I cosider maybe doing it this way:

```
POST /rest/bars/1/foos   { # Foo json object }
```

Above will create new Foo object and make association between this new object and Bar(id=1).

```
PUT /rest/bars/1/foos/2  { # Foo json object }
```

Above updates Foo(id=2) if there is such association with Bar(id=1) or if there isn't such association and Foo(id=2) exists in Foo table such association will be made.

If I would like to add/update only Foo without association i made sth like below:

```
POST /rest/foos
PUT  /rest/foos/2
```

If I would like to remove Foo(id=2)

```
DELETE /rest/foos/2
```

And if I only want to delete association between Bar(id=1) and Foo(id=2)

```
DELETE /rest/bars/1/foos/2
```

What do you think about such approach? And how would you handle this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your OneToMany relation [How to model parent child entities via REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786795/how-to-model-parent-child-entities-via-rest-and-jax-rs?rq=1) might help you.

The association with its parent is an attribute of the child resource so the OneToMany relation should be managed on the *many* side.

```
PUT /rest/bars/1/foos/2  { # Foo json object }
```

Is OK if your `foos` are only possible in connection with a `bar` but if they can also exist without a `bar` you should use a dedicated `foo` resource not subordinate to the `bar` resource. Think *aggregation* or *composition*.

> And if I only want to delete association between Bar(id=1) and
>   Foo(id=2)
>
> DELETE /rest/bars/1/foos/2

I would not use this approach instead update the `foo` with `id=2` to not be associated with `bar` 1 anymore.
A `DELETE /rest/bars/1/foos/2` should delete the full `foo` resource instead of only the association in my opinion.

Regarding ManyToMany relations you'll need a third resource to manipulate the join table directly. To simplify this a little bit this resource will only need the `POST` and `DELETE` actions defined.
`POST` to add a new associated pair: to ids, one for `bar` and one for `foo`.
`DELETE` to remove such a pair.

Comment: Ok in the case of \@OneToMany relationship it makes sense to make this associations on the Many side as there I can post/put/delete such association. But in the case of \@ManyToMany relationship  I consider how I can access Join Table directly in order to POST/DELETE this association 
wouldn't be DELETE /rest/bars/1/foos/2 be a good approach indicating what is deleted i.e. Bar 1 and Foo 2 relationship? other approach seems to be something like DELETE /rest/bar-foo-relationship/1+2

Comment: Is `foo` a child of `bar`? If not why isn't it `rest/foos/2/bars/1`? I would use something like the second approach your first approach has a problem because you create a new `foo` by posting to `bars/1/foos` so I would expect `bars/1/foos/2` to be a resource representing a `foo` but it would represent only the association between them. This would mix two different resource meanings.

Comment: Ok I have for instance Provider and Industry. There is many to many relationship between them i.e. Provider can belong to many Industries and Industry can have defined in it many Providers.  So Industries should be accessed and created without Providers, like /rest/industries and /rest/industries/1 also Providers should be accessed independently like /rest/providers/1. But to access on Provider its related Industries i think /rest/providers/1/industries will be logical. But how the best make association and remove it? Do you think /rest/provider-industry-relationship/{id1}+{id2} will be better

Comment: First try to find a better name for this relationship which is more domain centered.  If there is no better fitting name use this path but drop the `relationship` and use plural nouns. Or use `providersToIndustries/1to2` or use any separator you want. I think API design should be about semantics. You could also use query parameters to describe id1 and id2.

Comment: so maybe I finally do something like 
/rest/providers-industries/1+2 
or
/rest/providers-industries?providerId=1&industryId=2

Comment: My additional consideration is what about JAX-RS resource classes if I have ProviderResource class with @Path("/providers") and IndustryResource class with root path @Path("/industries") should I for this relationship create separate class ProviderIndustryRelationship class and add path @Path("providers-industries") or some bettern pattern is possible?

Comment: Yes I would create a standalone `ProviderIndustryRelationship` because the path `/providers-industries` is a REST resource in itself representing the `provider` - `industry` associated pairing. Maybe call it `...Pairing`. Creating a standalone resource class is also supporting the single responsibility concept and is expected in my point of view. And if the Pairing should become more than a simple join model you can simply expand your class.